# Zend_Validate_Date just doesn't work properly

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

It appears that `Zend_Validate_Date` just simply doesn't work properly. For example:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'yyyy'));
```

This is a simple validator that should only accept a four digit year, yet `$validator->isValid('1/2/3')` returns true! Really, Zend?

Or how about this:

```
$otherValidator = new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'));
```

Even with the above code, `$otherValidator->isValid('15/13/10/12/1222')` returns `true` too!

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.9. Is it just me or is this a really terrible validation class? (UPDATE: In other words, is there something wrong with my code, or is this a bug that should be submitted?)

Comment: What is the question?  Whether its a terrible validation class?

Comment: Not just you, its got problems [zf-7583](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7583) [zf-10030](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10030)

Comment: @thetaiko See the UPDATE at the end of my post.

Answer (score 6):

As the comments above say, apparently there's a bug with this class. Here is the workaround I came up with, using `Zend_Validate_Regex`:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Regex(
    array('pattern' => '/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/')
);
$validator->setMessage(
    "Date does not match the format 'mm/dd/yyyy'",
    Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH
);
```

Hopefully that will help someone else. Please note that I only want slashes as  separator, not dots or dashes.