# Zend_Validate_Date returns true on 2011-02-31

Tags: zend-framework

What should i do ?

```
$edit_end_date  = '2011-02-31';
$validator_date = new Zend_Validate_Date(array('format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'));  
$isval          =   $validator_date->isValid($edit_end_date);  
if((!$isval) || empty($edit_end_date))
    {
    echo "Please Enter Valid End Date. !";
    }else{
echo "Entered Is Valid End Date. !";
}
```

how come it returns true date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Zend API Docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html), it appears that Zend_Validate_Date will only validate whether the argument passed to it, is a valid date construct (also considers locale), it will not validate if the date actually exists.

**Zend_Validate_Date allows you to validate if a given value contains a date. This validator validates also localized input.**

-- Edit --

Looks like you can use [PHP's built in](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) `checkdate()` function to determine if a date is valid or not.

Comment: so please tell me what should i do for valid date?

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in data validation ([ZF-7583 at issue tracker](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7583)). Look at [Zend_Validate_Date just doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839489/zend-validate-date-just-doesnt-work-properly)

You can use regex validation like in answer to linked question, but it will only check for syntax, not if date exists for real. For this you can use `checkdate()` - as Mike Purcell suggested - combined with [Zend_Validate_Callback](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.callback):

```
$validator1 = new Zend_Validate_Regex(
    array('pattern' => '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/')
);
$validator1->setMessage(
    "Date does not match the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'",
    Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH
);

$validator2 = new Zend_Validate_Callback(function($value)) {
    // using checkdate() or other function
});
```